# How to add an attribute to a list item that is recorded in the Delta object?

Tags: quill

To implement a check-list feature with quill, I'm extending the ListItem class to add a "check" attribute. This is how I'm doing it.

```
class CheckListItem extends ListItem {

static create(value) {
  let node = super.create()
  node.setAttribute('check', 'todo')
  return node;
}

 ...
} 
CheckListItem.blotName = 'check'

...

List.defaultChild = "check"
List.allowedChildren = [CheckListItem]
```

When I inspect the element, I can see that the attribute has been added correctly to the `li` node. But it doesn't get recorded in the Delta object, so I cannot save the checklist state.

How can I make my custom attribute show up the the Delta object?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an [`Attributor`](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#attributors):

```js
const Check = new Parchment.Attributor.Attribute(
  'check', 
  'check',
  {scope: Parchment.Scope.BLOCK},
);
Quill.register(Check);
```

Now when you update your document:

```js
quill.setContents([
  {insert: 'foo'},
  {
    insert: '\n',
    attributes: {
      list: 'bullet',
      check: 'todo',
    },
  },
]);
```

...you'll get a DOM node with the correct attribute:

```html
<li check="todo">foo</li>
```

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/alecgibson/pen/ZEepoWG)

Comment: is there away to do the attributes in one line?
<p><span class="error">hellu</span> my <span class="error">nume</span is</p>
?
when i'm removing \n it's not working

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky you'll need to change `scope` to `Scope.INLINE`